# insert persian text in image in python, UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(256)

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

i want to insert persian text in image,
i am using this link using this [link](https://gist.github.com/amrza/04658c71ac02d82580855f89b9b3dff4)

here is the code:

```
import arabic_reshaper

from bidi.algorithm import get_display

from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

#fontFile = "/Users/amirreza/pil/Sahel.ttf"

imageFile = r'/content/flower_1.jpg'

#font = ImageFont.truetype(fontFile, 18)
image = Image.open(imageFile)

text = "سلام ایران"
reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text)    # correct its shape
bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)           # correct its direction

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.text((0, 0), bidi_text, (255,255,255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

image.save("output.png")
```

but this error happens:

```
enter coUnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(256)de here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default font in PIL does not support Arabic characters.

You must load a font file that does support arabic characters:

```py
arabic_font = ImageFont.truetype('ArbFONTS-Ubuntu-Arabic_B.ttf', 40)
```

Them pass it as an argument to the Drawtext function:

```py
draw.text((0, 0), bidi_text, (255,255,255), font=arabic_font)
```

**Warning** after this your code will run, but you need a font with support for Arabic characters, or your output will not display the text properly.

This two fonts have good support for Arabic fonts (imho):

- Arial (shipped on Windows. You might need a license from Monotype Corporation to use the font on your programs).
- Ubuntu Arabic (free to use for personal and commercial use).